# C program: Integer array pointer changes values when passed as parameter

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, parameters

My problem is that my integer array's values change when it is passed to the function **calculate**. The values are correct for indexes 0, and 2->5.

For some reason, indexes 1 and 6+ are not the correct values.

Below is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* generate_rand (int length, int MAX_ARRAY);
void calculate (int *array_ptr, int length, int *mean, int *sd);

main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a;
    printf("\nArray length?: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    int* array_ptr2;
    array_ptr2 = generate_rand(a, 100);
    //int mean, sd;
    int* *mean;
    int* *sd;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Array2: %d\n", *(array_ptr2 + i));
    }
    calculate(array_ptr2, a, *mean, *sd);
    //printf("Mean: %d\n", (int)*mean);
}

int* generate_rand (int length, int MAX_ARRAY) {
    int arr[length];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int r = rand()%MAX_ARRAY;
        arr[i] = r;
        printf("Rand: %d\n", arr[i]);
    }
    int *arrPtr;
    arrPtr = &arr[0];
    return arrPtr;
}

void calculate (int *array_ptr, int length, int *mean, int *sd) {
    int sum;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("Array: %d\n", *(array_ptr + i));
        sum += *(array_ptr + i);
        //array_ptr++;
        printf("Sum: %d, i:%d\n", sum, i);
    }
    //*mean = sum / length;
}
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: generate_rand is returning a pointer to the contents of a local variable, which is useless..

Comment: So you're saying that I should declare array_ptr2 just below the include statements? I just tried that and I am still getting the same result.

Comment: You must allocate your own array (using `malloc` or `calloc` or something), the one in `generate_rand` "disappears" at the end of the function. It seems you circumvented the warning about returning a local variable by putting it into a temporary pointer first.

Comment: More accurately, returning a pointer to a local variable results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @user1262552 Oli is saying that you need to find another solution to your problem. What is `generate_rand()` supposed to do? Is there a reason you are returning a `int*` rather than just a plain `int`?

Comment: @Code-Guru, the instruction for this problem states that generate_rand() must return a pointer to an array that is filled with random values.

Comment: After you fix the current problem, you may encounter problems with using pointers `mean` and `sd` in `main()` which are not initialized.

Comment: @user1262552 Then you need to allocate the memory for that array. At the moment, you are returning a pointer to a single `int`, not a pointer to a whole array of such.

Comment: @Code-Guru, dremalax said above to use malloc or calloc. I'm very new to C programming (if you can tell)... so how do I use those exactly when defining an array?

Comment: @user1262552 No problem. I suggest you first read your text book or google for more information on `malloc()`. If you have further questions, please come back and ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning the address of a local variable of a function. Local variables of functions cease to exist after a function has exited, so the returned pointer suddenly becomes dangling (as in, not pointing to anything useful).

You need to allocate memory for your array with `malloc`, because the memory returned from `malloc` will exist until it is freed with `free` (which you can call anytime afterwards).

```
int* generate_rand (int length, int MAX_ARRAY) {
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * length);

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int r = rand()%MAX_ARRAY;
        arr[i] = r;
        printf("Rand: %d\n", arr[i]);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

When you no longer need the array returned from this function, pass it to `free` to release the memory, e.g.:

```
int *arr = generate_rand(10, 100);
// do something with arr here...
free(arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

`generate_rand(`) is returning a pointer to `arr[0]` where `arr` is a local variable. The local variable goes out of scope as soon as the function, `generate_rand()`, returns. Once a variable is out of scope, there is no guarantee about its value, in fact, accessing an out of scope of variable is undefined.

One possible solution: `generate_rand()` can allocate the array `arr` on the heap, i.e. allocate memory using `malloc()`. Needless to say, the memory must be `free()`-ed as soon as it is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As you state in the comments, `generate_rand()` needs to return a pointer to an array that is filled with random values. At the moment, you are returning a pointer to the first element of a local array. As other's have stated, the memory of this array is only guaranteed to be available to your program inside of the `generate_rand()` function. In order to create an array which you can use anywhere in your program, you need to allocate the memory with `malloc()`. I suggest you research memory management further. You need to learn about both the `malloc()` and `free()` functions.